# how can I exclude some folders containing .vue files from being built in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, vuejs2

[image]

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ],
  module:{
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        exclude: [
          './src/components/Homepages/number1',
          './src/components/Homepages/number2'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

> I am trying to include just one of 'Homepages/number1', 'Homepages/number2', 'Homepages/number3' folders in my project conditionally and others shoud be excluded from the project when running **npm run build** to decrease my **dist** folder size. I am trying this code but I am sure its not the right solution. I am doing this config in babel.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [Copy plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/#ignoring-files):

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: path.posix.join(
            path.resolve(__dirname, "src").replace(/\\/g, "/"),
            "**/*"
          ),
          globOptions: {
            ignore: [
              // Ignore all `txt` files
              "**/*.txt",
              // Ignore all files in all subdirectories
              "**/subdir/**",
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    }),
  ],
};
```